# Control-M Execute SSIS package via batch file, capture ssis Error in calling batch file output

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, ssis, control-m

We have lots of SSIS packages that run via .bat(batch) files from Control-M. The issue we have is that if the SSIS package fails, the batch file ( executed via Control-M Job) never displays the the real SSIS error message, the production support team wants to see these errors within the batch file output logs, which gets displayed within control-m, instead of going separately to SSIS Error reporting.

so for example
Batch file error output is (Current output)

> Package execution on IS Server failed. Execution ID: 118475, Execution Status:4.
>   To view the details for the execution, right-click on the Integration Services Catalog, and open the [All Executions] report

but the real error in SSIS is (Expected output to be appended to current output)

> ExtractConform_Master:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Login failed for user 'UK\blah'.".
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Cannot open database "Blah" requested by the login. The login failed.".

Current Sample batch file looks like this
"

```
echo off

set PackageName=Publish.dtsx
set EnvironmentName=BlahEnvironment
set BasePath=%~dp0..

REM Parameters
REM ====================================================

set Cluster=Clustername
set Subcluster=SubclusterName
set QueueName=QueueName



"%DTExecFilePath%" /ISSERVER     "\%SSISCatalog%\%FolderName%\%ProjectName%\%PackageName%" /SERVER %SSISSERVER% /Envreference %env% /Par "$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)";True /Par "Cluster";%Cluster% /Par "Subcluster";%Subcluster% /Par "$Package::QueueName";%QueueName%

echo ERROR LEVEL is %ERRORLEVEL%

IF %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 EXIT /b 1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 EXIT /b 0 code here
```

Any Advice  ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the **Control-M for Database** module to run DTSX from SSIS SQL Server. This will allow you to use a *Database Job Type* where you can enable the option to **append** the DTSX execution output.